# Make a statefull class wait for a list to load

Tags: flutter, provider

Actually it was not a problem the list is not loaded but because of an attribute of an animation widget inside a statefull class I need to load the list to get its size.
I'm using the Provider's Consumer to access the list.
The problem is when I access this screen the console throws an error:
**Exception: Percent value must be a double between 0.0 and 1.0, but it's Infinity.**

but then the list loads and is ok.

`List<MemoCard?>? allCardsInDeck = [];`

```
Future<void> _loadAllMemoCardsInDeck() async {
    final QuerySnapshot snapDecks = await firestore.collection('users/$clientID/decks/${deck?.idDeck}/cards').get();
    allCardsInDeck = snapDecks.docs.map((e) => MemoCard.fromDocument(e)).toList();
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: Hey you can create some state like IDEL, BUSY, LOADING and can return widget according to state.
OR
check where you are using allCardsInDeck.length. if allCardsInDeck.length == 0 then use vlaue to 0 instead of do any operation like dividing.

Comment: To understand your problem in details you need to share your code where you are using allCardsInDeck list